# Is there a central / main context in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Here is my question: Consider Django or web2py in Python (as web frameworks) or Java WEB applications (being simple servlets apps or complex struts2/wicket/whatever frameworks). They share at least two things I like:

1. There's a Context environment or a way to access data out of the request or session contexts (i.e. global data, singletones, pools ... anything that can share in-memory values and behavior).
2. Classes are loaded/initialized ONCE. Perhaps i'm missing something but AFAIK in PHP a class is loaded and initialized in a PER REQUEST basis (so, in a regular class, if I (e.g.) modify a static value, this will live only in the current request, and even a simultaneous request hitting that value will get a different one).

Is there a way to get that in php? e.g. in Python/Django i can declare a regular class and that class can hold static data or be a true singleton (again: perhaps a pool or a kind of central queue manager), and will be the same object until the django server dies (note: modules in python are kept loaded in the python context when imported).

Comment: unless you're using some kind of application server, the script's environment is setup/torn down on a per-request basis. there's no persistence provided by PHP itself (ignoring $_SESSION) unless you provide it yourself.

Comment: [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php‎) offers the ability to store data to a cache which can persist across requests. But other than some system like that, no, as php exits completely after each request.

Comment: uuuh :( i had a long time with python and thought that php 5.5 would add something like that. a pity, i like that "feature" (the true feature is that the other tools i mentioned explicitly distinguish per-request code from non-per-request code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that PHP's "context" lives on a per-request basis is pretty much core to how the language works with web servers.

If you want to get it working more like Java or other languages where the data doesn't get reset every request, you basically have two options:

- Serialize data into a file, DB, whatever, and reload it on the next request
- Instead of serving your pages through a web server, write the server using PHP

Serializing data into storage and reloading it on subsequent requests is the typical approach.

Writing a server in PHP itself, while possible, is not something I would recommend. Despite much effort, PHP still has sort of bad memory management, and you are very likely to encounter memory leaks in long-running PHP processes.